# There exists a definition of order homomorphism?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory, definition, examples-counterexamples, order-theory

Let be $(X,\preccurlyeq)$ and $(Y\curlyeqprec)$ partial ordered sets so that let be $f$ a function form $X$ to $Y$. So if $\rightthreetimes$ and $\leftthreetimes$ was an operation on $X$ and an operation on $Y$ then it is usual to say that $f$ is a groupoid homomorphism if for any $x_1$ and $x_2$ in $X$ the equality
$$
f(x_1\rightthreetimes x_2)=f(x_1)\leftthreetimes f(x_2)
$$
holds so that I would say that $f$ is an order homomorphism if the inequality
$$
\tag{1}\label{1}x_1\preccurlyeq x_2
$$
implies the inequality
$$
\tag{2}\label{2}f(x_1)\curlyeqprec f(x_2)
$$

Now if $f$ was a bjiective groupoid homomorphism (namely a groupoid isomorphism) then it is not hard to show that even $f^{-1}$ is a groupoid homomorphism but I suspect that the same does not would be if $f$ was an order bjiective homomorphism (namely a groupoid isomorphism) since I know that actually many authors says that $f$ is an order isomorphism if it is a bijection such that the inequality
\eqref{1} holds if and only if the inequality \eqref{2} holds so that I suspect it would be better say that $f$ is a order homomorphism whether \eqref{1} holds if and only if \eqref{2} holds: so by this I thought to put a specific question where I ask to prove or disprove whether the inverse application of an order isomorphism is an order isomorphism with respect the (first) definition I gave; moreover, I would like to know if any author actually defines an order homomorphism. Could someone help me, please?

Comment: The usual definition of an order homomorphism is $(1)\implies(2),$ not $(1)\iff(2).$

An order isomorphism is a bijection $f$ such that both $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are order homomorphisms.

Comment: I do not understand your "even $f^{-1}$ is a group", nor "order bjiective homomorphism (namely a groupoid isomorphism)".

Comment: I wanted say "even $f^{-1}$ is a groupoid homomorphism".  Could I ask you some references about order homomorphism? Finally could I ask you if actually exists a counterexample showing that if $f$ is such that $(1)\Rightarrow (2)$ then the implication $(2)\Rightarrow(1)$ does not hold when $f$ is a bijection?

Comment: @AnneBauval I think what they are trying to say is that in the specific case of groups, if $f$ is a bijection and a homomorphim, $f^{.1}$ is also automatically a homomorphism. This is something specific to structures which only have function symbols.

Comment: @JonathanSchilhan That was not my point (he clearly said the same holds more generally for groupoids).

Comment: @JonathanSchilhan You are (quite) right: if $f$ is a group**oid** homomorphism then $f^{-1}$ is a group**oid** homomorphism whether $f$ is a bjiection so that I ask if an analogous thing happens when $f$ is a order homomorphism with respect the "weakly" definition.

Comment: @AnneBauval Your last comment is perfectly right.

Comment: @AnneBauval However, I was thinking that if $(1)$ implies $(2)$ then it is even possibile to simply say that $f$ is an increasing map so that it is possibile to use the substantive "homomorphism" for the double implication $(1)\Longleftrightarrow(2)$.

Comment: A counterexample is the bijection $f={\rm id}_X$, $X=Y=\{0,1\},$ $\preccurlyeq=\{(0,0),(1,1)\}$, $\curlyeqprec=\{(0,0),(1,1),(0,1)\}.$

Comment: @AnneBauval Ok, I honestly don't know what else one would try to convey with "I do not understand ...".

Comment: The two quotes which I didn't understand were soon corrected.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks for the counterexample. Could finally I ask you if you know some authors (I would understand if it is common but I could quote only [Fernando Hernandez-Hernandez](http://computo.fismat.umich.mx/~fhernandez/)) which use the adjective increasing if the implication $(1)\Rightarrow(2)$ holds?

Comment: 2 references for the definition of order homomorphism are given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_isomorphism#Definition): Bloch, Ethan D. (2011), *Proofs and Fundamentals: A First Course in Abstract Mathematics*, Undergraduate Texts in Mathematics (2nd ed.), Springer, pp. 276–277, ISBN 9781441971265 https://books.google.com/books?id=QJ_537n8zKYC&pg=PA276, and Schröder, Bernd Siegfried Walter (2003), *Ordered Sets: An Introduction*, Springer, p. 11, ISBN 9780817641283 https://books.google.com/books?id=2esoXnolEWgC&pg=PA11

Comment: The usual names in order theory don't seem to be "increasing/decreasing", but rather "monotone/antitone", or  "order preserving/order reversing" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function#In_order_theory

Comment: @AnneBauval Oh, really thanks for the nice references: they was useful. Obviously if you will write an answer I will accept it. Thanks really again! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual definition of an order homomorphism (also called "monotone", or "order preserving" map) is $(1)⟹(2),$ not $(1)⟺(2).$ Two  references for this definition are given [here on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_isomorphism#Definition):

- Bloch, Ethan D. (2011), *Proofs and Fundamentals: A First Course in Abstract Mathematics*, Undergraduate Texts in Mathematics (2nd ed.), Springer, [pp. 276–277](https://books.google.com/books?id=QJ_537n8zKYC&pg=PA276), ISBN 9781441971265, and
- Schröder, Bernd Siegfried Walter (2003), *Ordered Sets: An Introduction*, Springer, [p. 11](https://books.google.com/books?id=2esoXnolEWgC&pg=PA11), ISBN 9780817641283

An order isomorphism is a bijection $f$
such that both $f$
and $f^{−1}$
are order homomorphisms.

An example of a bijective order homomorphism which is not an order isomorphism is $f={\rm id}_X,$ $X=Y=\{0,1\},$ $≼=\{(0,0),(1,1)\},$ $⋞=\{(0,0),(1,1),(0,1)\}.$

Comment: Perfect: answer upvoted and approved. Thanks really for it! :-)